# Problema con bucle while

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ejercicio que esta en pseudocodigo y tengo que traducirlo a javascript. El pseudocodigo es el siguiente:

```
var
   num, cifra, i, n: enter;
fvar

num := 847250;

n := 3;

i := 1;


mientras (i < n) fpor

  cifra := num mod 10;

  num := num div 10;

  i := i + 1;

fmientras
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que mientras se refiere a un while i fpor a un { que abre las sentencias.

Lo que tengo que sacar es el resultado de "cifra", pero haciendo esto:

```
var num, cifra, i, n;
   
    num = 847250;
    
    n = 3;
    
    i = 1;
    
    
    while (i < n) {
    
      cifra = num % 10;
    
      num = num / 10;
    
      i := i + 1;
    
    }

console.log(cifra);
```

El resultado me da 5, pero el profesor me ha dicho que no es correcto.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya había sido formulada.

Comment: Hola Joan, la pregunta está bien formulada pero es duplicada de la que tú mismo hiciste. Cuando una pregunta se cierra, siempre puedes editarla y pedir su reapertura. Por favor, dale a [edit] a esta pregunta, selecciona todo y cópialo en la otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400022/duda-con-pesucodigo). Entonces pide la reapertura y añadiremos las respuestas ahí

Comment: Si, ya habia sido formulada, y fue cerrada por falta de detalles / clarificacion.... aunque te tengo una mala noticia... tambien me da 5 jaja.
Evita el cierre de la pregunta nuevamente, dado que tecnicamente estas poniendo lo mismo que antes.

Comment: Cre que la diferencia está en la división, en JS no existe el operador `div`, y `/` toma decimales

Comment: Pues el profe me coments que la solucion no es 5...

Comment: Prueba a mover el codigo dentro del while, en mi caso, lo puse debajo de la asignacion del num, por lo que en vez de 5, cifra dio 2.

Comment: Pensé que forzando las operaciones para que sean enteros (`parseInt()`) podría haber cambios, pero el resultado es 5.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = 847250;
    
    let n = 3;
    
    let i = 1;
    while (i < n) {
    
      //mientras (i < n) se ejecutara el codigo
      //(1 < 3) true
      //(2 < 3) true
      //(3 < 3) false, se detiene el bucle
      num = num / 10;
      //primera iteracion 84725
      //segunda iteracion 8472.5
      cifra = num % 10;
      //primera iteracion 5
      //segunda iteracion 2.5
      i = i + 1;
    
    }

console.log(cifra);
```

Te explico detalladamente como funciona el codigo para su entendimiento.

Comment: Es lo único que se puede cambiar.

Comment: Acabo de realizar este cambio y me da 2.

Comment: ¿Por qué primero la división y luego el módulo? en la pregunta están al revés.

Comment: solo lo cambie para mostrar otro resultado distinto

Comment: El tema es que en el siguiente pseudocdigo he de saber el valor que da cifra:

var
   num, cifra, i, n: enter;
fvar

num := 847250;

n := 3;

i := 1;


mientras (i < n) fpor

  cifra := num mod 10;

  num := num div 10;

  i := i + 1;

fmientras

pero pasandolo a formato algoritmico de javascript me da 5, pero el profe dice que no es 5.

Comment: es que en la primera iteracion el valor de cifra no se le aplica la division, como yo lo hice si por eso cambia el valor

Comment: edite el codigo para que veas su funcionamiento con mas claridad